# How can I split an image URL into two columns (date and name) in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm terrible with excel, and I'm currently looking to organise a list of different images based on dates. I have, for example:

/2019/08/JRP0004-50x50.jpg"

in one column. I want to split it so it appears like this:

/2019/08/

and

JRP0004-50x50.jpg"

in their own columns.

Comment: Will all your input be two folders, then the image/file?

Comment: Use Text To Columns, split on / and then recombine the first two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way this works is you show us what you tried first, so you can get help troubleshooting it, but I just did something like this so here's what worked for me.

Assuming your data is in cell A1, you can put this in Cell B1

```
=LEFT(A1,9)
```

And put this in cell C1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1;"")
```

then just drag the formulas down as far as you need

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it. I will show what I've done in future, I didn't realise I had to show examples (even though mine were way off base)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have folder names that aren't simply `####/##`, you can search for the `/` delimiter and work from there.

If your text is in `A1`, you can use this in `B1` to get the folder names:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",3)))
```

and this in `C1` for the filename:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(B1,A1)+LEN(B1),LEN(A1)-SEARCH(B1,A1)+LEN(B1))
```

[image]